# Display goes to sleep after application starts on Android 4.1.x

Tags: java, android, sleep, android-wake-lock

I've got application running on Android 4.0.4 successfully. However, if I run it on device with Android 4.1.x. it runs (by looking into the logs, I can see OnCreate starts), but displays goes black immediately. If I press power button, I can see aplication correctly running. Anybody experienced this? Please see the logs bellow:

```
09:46:07.260    19084   #19084  DEBUG   WakeLockManager acquireWakeLock(com.htc.launcher.AllAppsPagedView@41ca3290) tag=RosieScroll_2
09:46:07.265    19084   #19084  WARN    dalvikvm    disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
09:46:07.265    439 #439    WARN    dalvikvm    disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
09:46:07.270    439 #439    WARN    dalvikvm    disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
09:46:07.270    439 #439    WARN    dalvikvm    disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
09:46:07.270    439 #439    DEBUG   PowerManagerService acquireWakeLock(41fa0290): CPU_MIN_NUM , tag=RosieScroll_2, flags=0x400, pid=19084, uid=9999, mUserState=0x3
09:46:07.270    439 #439    DEBUG   PowerManagerService acquireWakeLock(41f20cb8): CPU_MIN_FREQ , tag=RosieScroll_2, flags=0x100, pid=19084, uid=9999, mUserState=0x3
09:46:07.355    19084   #19084  DEBUG   WakeLockManager releaseWakeLock(com.htc.launcher.AllAppsPagedView@41ca3290) tag=RosieScroll_2
09:46:07.355    19084   #19084  WARN    dalvikvm    disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
09:46:07.355    439 #439    DEBUG   PowerManagerService releaseWakeLock(41fa0290): CPU_MIN_NUM , tag=RosieScroll_2, flags=0x400
09:46:07.360    439 #439    DEBUG   PowerManagerService releaseWakeLock(41f20cb8): CPU_MIN_FREQ , tag=RosieScroll_2, flags=0x100
09:46:07.405    439 #439    WARN    CpuWake >>nativeAcquireCpuPerfWakeLock()
09:46:07.405    439 #439    WARN    CpuWake <<nativeAcquireCpuPerfWakeLock()
09:46:07.405    439 #439    INFO    ActivityManager START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.codevog.kiosk/.KIOSKActivity u=0} from pid 19084
09:46:07.410    439 #439    INFO    Intent  @test_code: getHtcIntentFlag: 0 obj: 1103583568
09:46:07.415    439 #439    DEBUG   ViewRootImpl    @@@- disable SystemServer HW acceleration
09:46:07.415    439 #439    DEBUG   PowerManagerService acquireWakeLock(4158e6e0): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK , tag=ActivityManager-Launch, flags=0x1, pid=439, uid=1000, mUserState=0x3
09:46:07.435    19084   #19084  INFO    Rosie.AllAppsCarouselF_ onPause
09:46:07.440    439 #439    DEBUG   PowerManagerService acquireWakeLock(41f564a8): SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK ON_AFTER_RELEASE , tag=KEEP_SCREEN_ON_FLAG, flags=0x2000000a, pid=439, uid=1000, mUserState=0x3
09:46:07.445    19084   #19084  DEBUG   Rosie.IndicatorPagedVi_ com.htc.launcher.AllAppsPagedView@41ca3290.onViewPause
09:46:07.445    19084   #19084  WARN    Rosie   closeFolder() -- Folder is null , AnimateClose? false
09:46:07.450    735 #735    DEBUG   CAT CatService: Return current sInstance
09:46:07.475    439 #439    INFO    ActivityManager Start proc com.codevog.kiosk for activity com.codevog.kiosk/.KIOSKActivity: pid=24785 uid=10265 gids={3003, 1028}
09:46:07.555    439 #439    WARN    dalvikvm    disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
09:46:07.560    439 #439    WARN    dalvikvm    disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
09:46:07.560    439 #439    WARN    dalvikvm    disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
09:46:07.560    439 #439    DEBUG   PowerManagerService acquireWakeLock(420172e8): CPU_MIN_FREQ , tag=WindowManager-ScreenRotation-Freq, flags=0x100, pid=439, uid=1000, mUserState=0x3
09:46:07.565    439 #439    WARN    dalvikvm    disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
09:46:07.565    439 #439    DEBUG   PowerManagerService acquireWakeLock(41fa26f0): CPU_MIN_NUM , tag=WindowManager-ScreenRotation-Num, flags=0x400, pid=439, uid=1000, mUserState=0x3
09:46:07.565    439 #439    DEBUG   PowerManagerService acquireWakeLock(41edc4f8): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK , tag=SCREEN_FROZEN, flags=0x1, pid=439, uid=1000, mUserState=0x3
09:46:07.565    439 #439    INFO    ActivityManager Config changed: {1.0 231mcc2mnc en_DK sw360dp w360dp h567dp nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.555 skin=default fontsize=3}
09:46:07.575    718 #718    INFO    CVW Dismiss CandidateViewWindow WCLID:0
09:46:07.650    24344   #24344  INFO    LiApplication   On configuration changed in application.
09:46:07.705    439 #439    INFO    VolumePanel ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
09:46:07.705    439 #439    DEBUG   VolumePanel forceTimeout
09:46:07.755    439 #439    DEBUG   StateMachine    handleMessage: E msg.what=131155
09:46:07.755    439 #439    DEBUG   StateMachine    processMsg: ConnectedState
09:46:07.755    439 #439    DEBUG   WifiStateMachine    ConnectedState{ what=131155 when=-3ms target=Handler (com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler) {41c2c148} arg1=2799 }
09:46:07.760    439 #439    DEBUG   StateMachine    processMsg: L2ConnectedState
09:46:07.760    439 #439    DEBUG   WifiStateMachine    L2ConnectedState{ what=131155 when=-6ms target=Handler (com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler) {41c2c148} arg1=2799 }
09:46:07.760    31564   #31564  DEBUG   wpa_supplicant  wpa_s 0x41aa16a8 cmd SIGNAL_POLL
09:46:07.760    31564   #31564  DEBUG   wpa_supplicant  RX ctrl_iface - hexdump(len=11): 53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 4c
09:46:07.760    31564   #31564  DEBUG   wpa_supplicant  ctrl_iface: SIGNAL_POLL
09:46:07.765    31564   #31564  DEBUG   wpa_supplicant  nl80211: survey data missing!
09:46:07.765    31564   #31564  DEBUG   wpa_supplicant  WiFi offload...TX packet: 20427
09:46:07.765    31564   #31564  DEBUG   wpa_supplicant  WiFi offload...TX failed packet: 38
09:46:07.765    31564   #31564  DEBUG   wpa_supplicant  WiFi offload...TX retry packet: 410
09:46:07.770    439 #439    DEBUG   WifiStateMachine    fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -52
09:46:07.775    439 #439    DEBUG   PowerManagerService releaseWakeLock(41edc4f8): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK , tag=SCREEN_FROZEN, flags=0x1
09:46:07.785    439 #439    DEBUG   StateMachine    handleMessage: X
09:46:07.835    600 #600    DEBUG   CarrierLabel    CarrierLabel mIntentReceiver : android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
09:46:07.835    600 #600    DEBUG   CarrierLabel    updateResources()
09:46:07.835    600 #600    WARN    CarrierLabel    updateNetworkNameExt: mSimState = UNKNOWN
09:46:07.835    600 #600    DEBUG   CarrierLabel    updateNetworkName showSpn=true spn=Telekom SK showPlmn=false plmn=T-Mobile SK
09:46:07.845    24785   com.codevog.kiosk   INFO    KIOSKActivity   onCreate START
```

Comment: Since it is not mine app, I started to study the source code and found BroadcastReceiver handling Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF, so that might explain that, even though, I don't know why this event is happening and why it behaves differently on Android 4.0 and Android 4.1

Comment: so it is DevicePolicyManager.lockNow() which triggers onPause(). Android 4.0 device I use is Amazon Kindle Fire HD, where lot of security customizations are not simply supported and ignored. That's why it doesn't pause. I need find out final solution and then will post it as an answer.